# compile redisql in cygwin without fenv.h

Tags: cygwin, redis

I'm trying to compile Redisql (AlchemyDatabase-0.1.6.tgz) in Cygwin but failed. This is because the header file fenv.h in row.c source file is not included in Cygwin's C standard library. I commented that out and Redisql successfully compiled. Is it OK to run this modified program, what's the risk of it's going to crash & eat the computer?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wikipedia, fenv.h "contains various functions and macros for manipulating the floating-point environment." So the software might work, but if you do floating point operations, the software might crash and burn. But it looks like Cygwin comes with fenv.h (http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-patches/2010-q3/msg00058.html)